# File upload from postman POST

Tags: post, file-upload, postman, rest

I am trying to post a file with last Postman version

[image]

and headers generated

[image]

but unfortunately when we check the request and body generated

[image]

it seems the file is not recognized or i don't know the problem, i tried several file type , update postman version, restart postman etc

postman version 8.10.0

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Collection Runner does not support uploading files. It's still be an open feature. You get more info here.

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3137

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5147

Comment: what is really really strange, i change with black theme and change file settings and now it works !? :/